# PHP Get / check value from associative array in array of individual stdClass Objects

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

Having real issues with this. I want to be able to get a value from this data which is returned via an API.

ie get value by

```
$CM_user_customfields['Organisation'],   
$CM_user_customfields->Organisation.
```

is that even possible? I have tried loops and rebuilding the array but i always end up with a similar results and perhaps overthinking it.

I can't use the [int] => as the number of custom fields will be changing a lot.

```
$CM_user_customfields =  $CM_details->response->CustomFields ;
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $CM_user_customfields, true ) . '</pre>';

// returns
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Key] => Job Title
            [Value] => Designer / developer
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Key] => Organisation
            [Value] => Jynk
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Key] => liasoncontact
            [Value] => Yes
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
...
```

many thanks, D.

Comment: _$CM_user_customfields->Organisation_ in this case you don't have no key organisation, so you have to return the correct array from your API.  So maybe you can access like this  _$CM_user_customfields->Key_ but your question isn't so clear

Comment: Think I've worked out what you mean. You could potentially do this with a mix of `array_search` and `array_column`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend convert to associative array first:

```
foreach($CM_user_customfields as $e) {
    $arr[$e->Key] = $e->Value;
}
```

Now you can access it as:

```
echo $arr['Organisation'];
```

You can also achieve it by: (PHP 7 can convert stdClass and will do the trick)

```
$arr = array_combine(array_column($CM_user_customfields, "Key"), array_column($CM_user_customfields, "Value")));
```

Comment: Omg - thanks so much. Literally going round in circles for a few hours. PHP7 used. $arr = array_combine(array_column($CM_user_customfields, "Key"), array_column($CM_user_customfields, "Value"));
print_r($arr);
echo $arr['Subscriber Type'];